# What is the analog video input pinout on the DJI FPV goggle?

Tags: wiring, accessories

I want to build an adapter cable for DJI FPV goggles analog video input. What is the correct connector type and the pinout for the analog signals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a project on [thingiverse](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3976175/files) that shows the pin connector for the video input of the DJI goggles.

It's a 4 pin 3.5mm jack with the following connections

- sleve - GND
- ring 2 - Video
- ring 1 - Right audio channel
- tip - Left audio channel